# When is the best time to use WebSockets in node?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am working on an client/server node+react application that displays logs. I want the user to have a constant stream of data flowing in, or at least appear to be. Is the most efficient way to use a Websocket in node, and just connect the client to it?

Comment: Unfortunately, your question is, at best, asking for opinions, and is completely too broad.  The only way to determine what is "most efficient" for your code is to have knowledge of the code and perform detailed profiling;  even if there were people here that had knowledge of your code, they would still be just providing their opinion, which isn't how this site works. see [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: @Claies I don't agree.  The wording of the question isn't ideal, but this isn't a question about efficiency... it's about technology choice.  There are only a couple technologies that can be used on the browser this way, and they have specific tradeoffs.  This question is on-topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're only streaming data from the server to the client, and that data is text, there is no need for Web Sockets.

[Server-Sent Events (SSE)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events) and the [EventSource API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventSource) are a simpler choice.  It's specifically designed to update the client as things happen, and sounds like a good fit for your use case.  They remain connected, will auto-reconnect if the connection is lost, and can support resuming from where they left off.

Web Sockets are more appropriate for when you want bi-directional data streaming.